# WPF ValidationTemplate doesn't work on DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Validation.ErrorTemplate:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Opacity="0.8" Width="64" Height="64"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}" />
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

If I use this on a TextBox everything behaves as I want it:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Firstname, 
                    ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                    NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"/>
```

But if I use it on DataGrids DataGridTextColumn, nothing happens if an error occurs:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Firstname"
                      Binding="{Binding Firstname,
                                ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
                                NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                       Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"/>
```

What is wrong with it?

Thank you in advance.